# How to use handlebars for autocomplete search bar with javascript?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, autocomplete, handlebars.js, ghost-blog

Currently I am working to make an autocomplete search bar for ghost cms and I have to use handlebars for it. I have done it using html, which is wrong; so what can I do to implement a handlebars template?
This is the html part:

```
<div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
   <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

Javascript part is:

```
<script>
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  var currentFocus;
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        currentFocus++;
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
        currentFocus--;
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });
  function addActive(x) {
    if (!x) return false;
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }
 document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
}

var countries = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antigua","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bermuda","Bhutan","];

autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), countries);
</script>
```

So, my problem is that I am doing this in a .hbs file. I don't know how to use handlebars for the search functionality.
If I try to create a

```
{{#each}} 
  {{somedata}}
{{/each}}
```

It doesn't work. How should I link my handlebars part with my javascript part? I have seen people doing it with jquery but it just went over my head.
So can anyone help please?
PS: If you are unable to understand I can also share more details.

Answer (score 0):

Handlebar files are rendered by the node/express server. Are you using proper route handlers which also render the hbs file before sending the result?

wrt Ghost CMS, is this hbs file going to be a partial or an entirely new page?

If it is a partial, is the file being rendered properly? (you can use inspect element after the page as rendered to check it)

If it is an entirely new page, are the routes properly configured in the routes.yaml file?

Comment: Thanks Yagnesh, I have done it using simple XmlHttpRequest and mustache.It is working now even though it is not done using handlebars.